# How to change the default editor for a file type in Mac OSx?

Tags: osx

The default editor for java files on my Mac seems to have been set to Xcode, but I want to change it to be the basic TextEditor.  I've looked in preferences for the association, but it's not there.  How do I change the default editor?

Comment: http://osxdaily.com/2009/10/25/change-file-associations-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: @slm may as well make that into an answer.

Comment: There is an SE site for questions related to Mac: http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This link provides the details on how to do this, titled: [Change File Associations in Mac OS X]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ2qv.png).

*excerpt of details from that link*

> Note this will impact all of a certain file format type, meaning changing this for one PDF will impact all PDF’s, and so on.
>
> 1. Find the file type(s) that you want to change the application to open with
> 2. Get Info about a file that is of that file type, say a .mov
> 3. Click the ‘Open With’ arrow to expand an application list
> 4. Choose the application you want all files of this type to open with (in this example we’ll use VLC to open all .mov files)
> 5. Click “Change All” and then “Continue” when the confirmation dialog appears
>
> [image: ss of dialog]
>
> **NOTE:** Now all of the files of that type will open in the application you specified. You can do this with any file type to keep things consistent.

Comment: Just a note if you don't read the answer properly like me! You need to choose "Get Info" not "Open With" from the context menu. More here http://superuser.com/a/1028248/291067